# Is modifying a variable in its declaration statement well-defined?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

For example:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int i = i=0; //no warning
    cout << i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled in vs2015 with no warning and output `0`. Is this code snippet well-defined although it seems a little weird?

However, in this [online compiler](https://wandbox.org/) (`g++ prog.cc -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17`) it throws a warning of:

```
prog.cc: In function '`int main()`':  
prog.cc:8:12: warning: operation on '`i`' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
     `int i=i=0;`
```

Comment: Note that the term "modifying" is not synonymous with "assigning" here. I'm pretty sure something like `int i = i += 5` would _not_ be well-defined. I have no idea about this though.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts What about `int i = i&0;` ? "Assignment" maybe is better here,but "modifying" is ok.Because what you said is modifying on the basis of it's undefined value,which is another situation of modifying.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know the answer, but is there any reason you need to know this other than idle curiosity?

Comment: I'd be concerned that the standard may permit `i=0` to run, then `i` to be initialized to an unspecified state, then `i` initialized from `i`.  I'd also be concerned that writing/reading to `i` prior to its first initliaization may be undefined instead of just an unspecified value.  The fact you are using `int` makes me less certain.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Not only curiosity about the result,I'm confused that why such statement is allowed in c++ like `int i=i=0` rather than `int i=0`.It seems like the `i` is used before its definition.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two possible cases, depending on whether the object's lifetime has begun.  This is determined by the first rule in `[basic.life]`:

> The lifetime of an object or reference is a runtime property of the object or reference. An object is said to have non-vacuous initialization if it is of a class or aggregate type and it or one of its subobjects is initialized by a
>   constructor other than a trivial default constructor. [ Note: Initialization by a trivial copy/move constructor is non-vacuous initialization. — end note ] The lifetime of an object of type `T` begins when:
>
> - storage with the proper alignment and size for type `T` is obtained, and
> - if the object has non-vacuous initialization, its initialization is complete, except that if the object is a union member or subobject thereof, its lifetime only begins if that union member is the initialized member in the union, or as described in (`[class.union]`).

1. Objects of class or aggregate type

   ```
   std::string s = std::to_string(s.size()); // UB
   ```

   In this case, the lifetime of the object doesn't start until initialization is complete, so this rule in `[basic.life]` is applicable:

   > Similarly, before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated or, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, any glvalue that refers to the original object may be used but only in limited ways. For an object under construction or destruction, see (`[class.cdtor]`). Otherwise, such a glvalue refers to allocated storage, and using the properties of the glvalue that do not depend on its value is well-deﬁned. The
   >   program has undefined behavior if:
   >
   > - the glvalue is used to access the object, or
   > - the glvalue is used to call a non-static member function of the object, or
   > - the glvalue is bound to a reference to a virtual base class, or
   > - the glvalue is used as the operand of a `dynamic_cast` or as the operand of `typeid`.

   In this example, the glvalue is used to access a non-static member, resulting in undefined behavior.
2. Objects of primitive type

   ```
   int i = (i=0); // ok
   int k = (k&0); // UB
   ```

   Here, even though there is an initializer, the initialization cannot be non-vacuous because of the type.  Therefore, the object's lifetime has started and the above rule does not apply.

   Still, the existing value in the object is indeterminate (unless the object has static storage duration, in which case static initialization gives it a value of zero).  A glvalue referring to an object with indeterminate value must never undergo lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.  Thus "write-only" operations are permitted, but most<sup>1</sup> operations reading the indeterminate value lead to undefined behavior.

   The applicable rule is found in `[dcl.init]`:

   > If no initializer is speciﬁed for an object, the object is default-initialized. **When storage for an object with automatic or dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object has an indeterminate value**, and if no initialization is performed for the object, that object retains an indeterminate value until that value is replaced. [ Note: Objects with static or thread storage duration are zero-initialized, see (`[basic.start.static]`). — end note ]
   >
   > **If an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, the behavior is undefined except in the following cases**:
   >
   > - If an indeterminate value of unsigned narrow character type or `std::byte` type is
   >     produced by the evaluation of:
   >
   >   - the second or third operand of a conditional expression,
   >   - the right operand of a comma expression,
   >   - the operand of a cast or conversion to an unsigned narrow character type or `std::byte` type, or
   >   - a discarded-value expression,
   >
   >   then the result of the operation is an indeterminate  value.
   > - If an indeterminate value of unsigned narrow character type or `std::byte` type is produced by the evaluation of the right operand of a simple assignment operator whose first operand is an lvalue of unsigned narrow character type or std::byte type, an indeterminate value replaces the value of the object referred to by the left operand.
   > - If an indeterminate value of unsigned narrow character type is produced by the evaluation of the initialization expression when initializing an object of unsigned narrow character type, that object is initialized to an indeterminate value.
   > - If an indeterminate value of unsigned narrow character type or `std::byte` type is produced by the evaluation of the initialization expression when initializing an object of `std::byte` type, that object is initialized to an indeterminate value.

---

<sup>1</sup> There's a narrow exception for using character types to copy indeterminate values, making the destination value also indeterminate.  The value still can't be used in other operations such as bitwise operators or arithmetic.

Comment: So what about the evaluation order issue? If the side effect of the initializer is not sequenced before the initialization, the behavior is still undefined.

Comment: @xskxzr: You're referring to cases where the eventual value is different, like `int x = (x = 1) - 1;` ?  I'll look into that one.

Comment: Even if the eventual value is the same, it may still be undefined. See [here](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#10.sentence-3).

Comment: @xskxzr: Wouldn't it be nice if the Standard actually gave a formal definition of *side effect*?

Comment: [Here](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#7.sentence-1) is the definition (though may be informal).

Comment: @xskxzr: Yes I found that one, sadly it doesn't say whether initialization is or is not a side effect (and neither do the sections on declaration statements or initialization say whether those have side effects).  It may not be actually be possible to write a definitive rule for that, for example platforms which load initialized constant data as a section already having its values, would never "modify" the object after its storage is obtained.

Comment: @xskxzr: The compilers don't even seem to know, [this example](http://rextester.com/MOZ71519) results in an error but the error message is clearly wrong (the object's lifetime *has* started)

Comment: I'd argue the initialization is a side effect since it modifies an object. Loading initialized constant data and such is probably fair play under the as-if rule and not indication of semantics.

Comment: I post a discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/std-discussion/GdnH-SfYKXQ).

Comment: I wonder why the authors of standards maintain some of the guaranteed behaviors associated with character types while gutting them so thoroughly as to make them useless, and not providing any way of achieving what would have been useful common semantics (e.g. given an lvalue that might hold a useful value, return its defined value, if it has one, or an Unspecified value if it doesn't).  If the authors of the Standard aren't going to maintain strong enough semantics to make the special character-type-related guarantees useful, why not drop the guarantees altogether?

Comment: @supercat: I think these semantics are pretty darn useful considering padding bytes -- calling `memcpy` for example results in unspecified contents of padding in the destination (harmless) whereas without this permission it would be undefined behavior.

Comment: @BenVoigt: If the destination would merely hold Unspecified values I wouldn't complaining.  The problem is that the Standard is written to make the destination Indeterminate.  If `struct1` or `struct2` contains any indeterminate bytes, then something like `memcmp(&s1, &s2, sizeof s1)` will invoke UB even in cases where there's a mismatch earlier in the structure.  Such things might not matter if compiler writers consistently recognized that "clever" doesn't imply "not stupid", but some of them don't seem to.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Further, I'm not sure what useful optimizations are allowed by the rules as written that would not also be allowed by defining the behavior of Indeterminate Values of all integer type as being like non-deterministic mathematical integers whose range is not limited to their type, except that a casting operator would arbitrarily select a value of the target type in Unspecified fashion from among the valid possibilities.  So if `q` is indeterminate, then `short x=q | 1; int y = (int)x, z = (int)x;` would set `y` and `z` to an independent odd numbers within the rage of `int`.

Comment: @supercat: You forgot trap representations.  On most systems, only floating-point types have them (e.g. IEEE "signalling NaN") but the C standard allows any fundamental type except the character types to have trap representations.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Trap representations are allowed only for integer types that take N bits of storage but have less than 2**N possible values.  On the vast majority of implementations, no such types exist.  Perhaps I should have said "all integer types which are not specified as having trap representations", but my key point was that the behavior of Indeterminate Value should be defined loosely enough to let compilers allow useful optimizations, but strongly enough that code which could tolerate any bit pattern an object could possibly hold need not initialize it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is modifying variable in its declaration statement well-defined?

```
int i = i=0;//no warning
```

The statement above is **initialization** and is well-defined since the two `i`'s are in the same scope.

As per [basic.scope.pdecl#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.scope.pdecl#1)

> The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its complete
>   declarator and before its initializer (if any), except as noted below.
>   [ Example:
>
> ```
> unsigned char x = 12; // Warning -Wunused-variable
> { unsigned char x = x; }
>                 ^ warning -Wuninitialized
> ```
>
> Here the second x is initialized with its own (indeterminate) value. — end example ]

In the example, the second `x` is in a different block scope, its value is then indeterminate. And will have a warning:

`warning: 'x' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]`

Given the fact that local variables with automatic storage will have indeterminate value if not initialized, I believe there's an assignment taking place which has this order.

```
int (i = (i = 0));
```

**Example**

```
int x; // indeterminate
int i = i = x = 2; // x is assigned to two, then x's value is assigned to i
cout << x << " " << i; // i = 2, x = 2
```

Comment: This isn't the what OP asked

Comment: @PasserBy, i'm basing it from the title and OP's last comment "I'm confused that why such statement is allowed in c++ like `int i=i=0` rather than `int i=0`.It seems like the `i` is used before its definition."

Comment: @PasserBy, feel free to help me improve my answer if you think it's completely out of scope.